# dict to dataframe key and values as columns?

Tags: python

I have a dict like:

```
`{'10/12/2020': 'Hello', '11/12/2020': 'Bye'}
```

I want to convert this to a pandas dataframe such that a column is the key and another column is values. How can I do this?

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` does not work

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you want?:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'10/12/2020': 'Hello', '11/12/2020': 'Bye'}

df = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
print(df)
```

output:

```
            0      1
0  10/12/2020  Hello
1  11/12/2020    Bye
```

- Caustion: Before 3.7(3.6 for CPython) version python interpreter, dictionaries don't ensure ordering. You should use `collections.OrderedDict` for ordered dict for those versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem if you use the list format.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'10/12/2020': 'Hello', '11/12/2020': 'Bye'}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df
10/12/2020  11/12/2020
0   Hello   Bye
```

Answer (score 0):

A key-value dictionary is more akin to a `Series`, try doing a `Series` and then converting that to a `DataFrame`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'10/12/2020': 'Hello', '11/12/2020': 'Bye'}
>>> pd.Series(data).to_frame("whatever you want the column name to be")
           whatever you want the column name to be
10/12/2020                                   Hello
11/12/2020                                     Bye
>>> pd.Series(data).to_frame("whatever you want the index name to be").T
                                       10/12/2020 11/12/2020
whatever you want the index name to be      Hello        Bye
```